# Using a for loop to populate an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a function that takes an array, consisting of 3 sets of strings. For each set of strings, the function should spit out 2 resulting integers/numbers.

[Link to the jsfiddle of work in progress](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/eXY3F/1/)
So if the input is

```
["10:00AM-12:30PM","02:00PM-02:45PM","09:10AM-09:50AM"]
```

I'm trying to get the function, by using a for-loop, to spit out 2 minute counts for each element of the array (a total of 6 minute counts, 2 per string).

I'm thinking I need the results stored in an object? Or maybe an array, consisting of objects? I'm a little bit confused here.

I'm confused as to how to organize it so that whatever is returned from the function, I can easily access it.

So maybe an array of 3 objects is returned is the best way to do it, with each object consisting of:

```
1st identifier key: an identifier of some sort (perhaps using the [i] from the for loop),
2nd key/property time1min: with the value being time1min (which is the 1st minute count),
3rd property time2min: with the value being time2min for that string.
```

As you can see from my jsfiddle above, I'm lost as to how to output to an object, or to an array of objects.

Comment: Your logic is all fine, and I think returning an array of objects is a good strategy. In your fiddle though, you just don't `alert()` correctly. It's an array so you need an index like `alert(results[0].time1min);`

Comment: Thank you. End of the day for me I tend to make mindless mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

results is an array; so `results[0].time1min`
Try using `console.log(results);` instead. It plays nicer than alerts.